# FileZilla makes my hoster block me

Tags: windows, ftp

> It's like in **The Beatles**:
>   "Yesterday,
>   All my troubles seemed so far away,
>   Now it looks as though they're here to
>   stay..."

Well I hope to solve my problem with your help. When I make an attempt to login via FTP to my files it sends me an error saying, that `login failed`. I spoke with support from my host and they say, that they had many problems with customers who use this FTP client. Unfortunately I can't use anything else at work.

First the hoster log gave:
`89.235.255.112 # lfd: (PERMBLOCK) 89.235.255.112 has had more than 4 temp blocks in the last 86400 secs - Sun Nov  7 09:59:57 2010`

Next after clearing the log, the error was
`89.235.255.112 # lfd: 10 (ftpd) login failures from 89.235.255.112 (EE/Estonia/89-235-255-112.saturn.infonet.ee) in the last 300 secs - Mon Nov  8 11:53:48 2010`

One of my friends told me, that the settings of the program might cause this problem, but I don't know which ones might be responsible for that. Since at home I use same FileZilla and no problems occur.

**UPD:** Current settings: http://flic.kr/p/8RNrjo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default connection timeout value in Filezilla is 20 seconds.  So, if you don't transfer anything within that time frame, Filezilla logs you out, and then logs you back in when you do something on the client.

Perhaps also the fact that Filezilla, if the login fails, retries right away is tripping your hosts defense systems.

Evidently your host doesn't like flapping FTP sessions, so I'd go into Settings -> Connections, and change the timeout value to something very long, like 600.  I'd also disable reconnection attempts.

Comment: Okey. I will immediately try that out. Also 0 should disable timeout at all.